# Zoom HERE maps to show all markers Android

Tags: android, maps, here-maps-rest

I have multiple locations that I am displaying on HERE maps in my Android app. There are in all 4 markers, out of which 3 markers are in one city and 1 is in another city. Currently, my map zooms to a level where only the 3 markers in one city are visible, whereas the 4th one is not visible. In order to see that marker, I have to zoom out a considerable level.

Is there a way, I can show all the markers within the bounds of the map?

Here is my code:-

```
 m_map = mapFragment.getMap();
                m_map.setZoomLevel((m_map.getMaxZoomLevel() + m_map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
                m_map.setMapScheme(Map.Scheme.NORMAL_DAY);

  final GeoCoordinate finalZoomLatLng = m_map.getCenter();
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            m_map.setCenter(finalZoomLatLng, Map.Animation.NONE);
            m_map.zoomTo(m_map.getBoundingBox(), Map.Animation.NONE, Map.MOVE_PRESERVE_ORIENTATION);
        }, 1000);
```

**EDIT**

With the help of Rahul's answer I have achieved something like so:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++)
{
    final GeoCoordinate latLng = m_getPosition(tasks[i]);
    LatLng mLatLng = new LatLng(latLng.getLatitude(), latLng.getLongitude());
    mLatLngBounds.include(mLatLng);
}

GeoCoordinate finalZoomLatLng = new GeoCoordinate(mLatLngBounds.build().getCenter().latitude, mLatLngBounds.build().getCenter().longitude);
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                m_map.setCenter(finalZoomLatLng, Map.Animation.NONE);
                m_map.zoomTo(new GeoBoundingBox(finalZoomLatLng, 0.0f, 200000.0f), Map.Animation.NONE, Map.MOVE_PRESERVE_ORIENTATION);
            }, 1000);
```

Now with this, the map is zoomed in the center of the map with all the locations around it. However, there is no marker at this location, so I have to zoom out a bit to see all markers. How can I solve this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this [thread](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/map-objects/app/src/main/java/com/here/android/example/map/objects/MapFragmentView.java)

Answer (score 1):

Same thing I achieved using this.

```
val geoCoordinateList = ArrayList<GeoCoordinate>()
val geoBoundingBox = GeoBoundingBox.getBoundingBoxContainingGeoCoordinates(geoCoordinateList)
map.zoomTo(geoBoundingBox, Map.Animation.LINEAR, Map.MOVE_PRESERVE_TILT)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> You have to use the CameraUpdate class to do (probably) all programmatic map movements.
>
> To do this, first calculate the bounds of all the markers like below:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
//All Marker List to get Position
for (Marker marker : markers) {
 builder.include(marker.getPosition());
}
//Create Latlong Bounds.
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
```

> Then obtain a movement description object by using the factory: CameraUpdateFactory lime below :

```
int padding = 0; // offset from edges of the map in pixels


CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
```

> Now we can use that in Map like below:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(cu);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using HERE maps for displaying the maps and not Google maps.

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar here which map you are using that is customized map.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LatLngBounds.Builder()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.Builder) to make multiple markers to viewable under map.

It has a method [include](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.Builder.html#include(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)), which allow you to add multiple LAT LNG locations.

```
val bounds: LatLngBounds = locatebuilder.build() // locatebuilder is LatLngBounds.Builder
val padding = 200 // offset from edges of the map in pixels
val cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding)
mMap!!.animateCamera(cu)
```

**EDIT**

Make a new list of markers when you're adding it inside map

```
for (mark in markers) { // markers is a list of markers added in the map
    locatebuilder.include(mark.position)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rahul. How can I make this work with HERE maps?

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar I have added some info in my answer. check now

Comment: Thanks again. Is mMap your Here maps object?

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar yes.

Comment: I do not get an animateCamera() for my HERE map object. Do I have to include some dependency for this?

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar No, mMap is the GoogleMap object and it has a method called animateCamera

Comment: I am using HERE maps. So how can I use it with HERE maps object?

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar I'm afraid, I never used HERE maps

Answer (score 0):

According this issue: https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/issues/176 you need to zoom like this:

```
private void navigateToMapMarkers(List<MapMarker> markers, int padding) {
        // find max and min latitudes and longitudes in order to calculate
        // geo bounding box so then we can map.zoomTo(geoBox, ...) to it.
        double minLat = 90.0d;
        double minLon = 180.0d;
        double maxLat = -90.0d;
        double maxLon = -180.0d;

        for (MapMarker marker : markers) {
            GeoCoordinate coordinate = marker.getCoordinate();
            double latitude = coordinate.getLatitude();
            double longitude = coordinate.getLongitude();
            minLat = Math.min(minLat, latitude);
            minLon = Math.min(minLon, longitude);
            maxLat = Math.max(maxLat, latitude);
            maxLon = Math.max(maxLon, longitude);
        }

        GeoBoundingBox box = new GeoBoundingBox(new GeoCoordinate(maxLat, minLon),
                new GeoCoordinate(minLat, maxLon));

        ViewRect viewRect = new ViewRect(padding, padding, m_map.getWidth() - padding * 2,
                m_map.getHeight() - padding * 2);
        m_map.zoomTo(box, viewRect, Map.Animation.LINEAR, Map.MOVE_PRESERVE_ORIENTATION);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the padding on the map before you apply the zoom

```
// (left, Top, right, Bottom)
map.setPadding(100, 100, 800, 400)
```

then you create the GeoBoundingBox and implement the zoom, or if you are getting a calculated route then you can get it in this way:

```
routeResult.route.boundingBox?.let { boundingBox ->
      map.zoomTo(boundingBox, Map.Animation.BOW, Map.MOVE_PRESERVE_ORIENTATION)
}
```

I'm using HERE maps 3.18.2 version

Answer (score 0):

You can use the boundingBox of the map route that is calculated.

```
val boundingBox = mapRoute?.route?.boundingBox
```

Or if it is null or you want to create boundingBox for specific markers, use this method :

```
val geoCoordinateList = arrayListOf<GeoCoordinate>()
selectedMarkersOrLocations.forEach {
    geoCoordinateList.add(GeoCoordinate(it.latitude?:0.0, it.longitude?:0.0))
}
val boundingBox = GeoBoundingBox.getBoundingBoxContainingGeoCoordinates(geoCoordinateList)
```

Then set the zoom with padding to the boundingBox :

```
val dpPadding = 100   //you can change this
val padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dpPadding.toFloat(), resources.displayMetrics)

if (boundBox != null && (mHereMap?.width != 0 || mHereMap?.height != 0)){
    val viewRect = ViewRect(padding, padding, (mHereMap?.width?:0) - padding * 2, (mHereMap?.height?:0) - padding * 2)
    map.zoomTo(boundBox, viewRect, Map.Animation.LINEAR, Map.MOVE_PRESERVE_ORIENTATION)
}
```