# Zoom HERE maps to show all markers Flutter

Tags: flutter, here-api, heremaps

I have multiple locations that I am displaying on HERE maps in my Flutter app. There are in all 4 markers, out of which 3 markers are in one city and 1 is in another city. Currently, my map zooms to a level where only the 3 markers in one city are visible, whereas the 4th one is not visible. In order to see that marker, I have to zoom out a considerable level.

Is there a way, I can show all the markers within the bounds of the map?

I have got answer for android but not for Flutter.

[Zoom HERE maps to show all markers Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58056090/zoom-here-maps-to-show-all-markers-android)

Comment: Hello there, please post the code you already have, so people can assist you with your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on this [answer on android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427622/14990656). I have tried in flutter and it worked.

```
 GeoBox target = GeoBox.containingGeoCoordinates(geoCoordinateList);
_hereMapController.camera
      .lookAtAreaWithOrientation(target, MapCameraOrientationUpdate(20, 0));
```

`geoCoordinateList` is a list of `GeoCoordinates` of `MapMarker` visible on `HERE map`

if you are using it on button click then use it directly. if you are using it directly after adding geocoordinates to geoCoordinateList then use it with delay

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10)).then((value) {
  GeoBox target = GeoBox.containingGeoCoordinates(geoCooList);
  _hereMapController.camera
      .lookAtAreaWithOrientation(target, MapCameraOrientationUpdate(20, 0));
});
```